# SQL query to generate weekly and daily loggedin duaration for user (using SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table strutcure in following format, need to generate total time spent on site by user in hours and mins daily and weekly and monthly, need sql query to generate report.

Table name LoginReport

```
      userid                             LoginTime                    LogoutTime

     PersonA                          2018-11-19 13:02:33.780      2018-11-19 13:03:44.793

    PersonA                           2018-11-19 13:11:06.370    2018-11-19 13:12:17.290

    PersonB                          2018-11-19 13:00:03.257     2018-11-19 13:01:23.067

    PersonB                          2018-11-19 12:38:35.400     2018-11-19 12:39:04.843
```

expected result

```
userid                                    Daily_Duration      Weekly_duration

PersonA                                  X hrs y mins         X hrs y mins

PersonB                                  X hrs y mins         X hrs y mins
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: userid                                                        Daily_Duration      Weekly_duration
                                                                 (in hrs and mins)     (in hrs and mins)
ba556ffe-4cbc-4990-94ff-2429f7d3d99a       X hrs y mins         X hrs y mins

47f66c04-4dfa-4378-b608-00134b23cb76      X hrs y mins          X hrs y mins

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead.

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, SUM() etc.

Comment: Have edited my question with expected result and table structure m using sql server 2016

Comment: Sample data like a, b and c is much easier than ba556ffe-4cbc-4990-94ff-2429f7d3d99a, ba556ffe-4cbc-4690-94ff-2429f7d3d99a and ba556gfe-4cbc-4990-94ff-2429f7d3d99a.

Comment: What is "daily duration"?  What is "weekly duration"?  I understand duration, but not what you mean by "daily" and "weekly".

Comment: @Naveen Expected result is "x hours ..." You're just not trying! The reason for posting **real** output is to allow others to see and evaluate the logic you discuss (and potentially the logic they write to solve your problem) against the sample data you provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
with cte as 
(
select userid, cast(LoginTime as date) as ldate, DATEPART( wk, cast(LoginTime as date)) as wk,LoginTime,LogoutTime
from tablename
)

select userid,daily_duration,weekly_duration from
(
select userid, ldate,wk,datediff(hh,min(LoginTime),max(LogoutTime)) as daily_duration from cte
group by userid,ldate,wk
)A inner join 
(
select userid,wk,datediff(hh,min(LoginTime),max(LogoutTime)) as weekly_duration from cte
group by userid,wk
)B on A.userid=B.userid and a.wk=b.wk
```

Answer (score 0):

Daily duration means you need have to specify the cases like

> need columns like date and month
>
> Otherwise you need a input parameters as for which date and and month you need the out put
> query can give the average of all daily and monthly durations

I think the following function is use full for you

```
 CREATE FUNCTION  [DBO].[ConvertMinToHours]
    (
    @Min int
        
    )
    RETURNS varchar(30) 
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @HOUR INT = (@Min/60)
    set @Min=@Min-(@HOUR*60)
    declare @InHours varchar(30)=CONCAT(@HOUR,'hrs',Space(1),@Min,'min')
    return @InHours
    END
    
    
    
    SELECT USERID,[DBO].[ConvertMinToHours](sum (DATEDIFF (mi,LOGINTIME,LOGOUTTIME))) 
    FROM LOGINREPORT group by userId, cast(LOGINTIME as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me :)

```
select t2.USERID,Data,Data1 from  
(SELECT USERID,(sum (case when Logouttime is null or Logouttime ='' then 0 else datediff(Minute,LoginTime,Logouttime) end)) as Data
FROM LOGINREPORT  where datepart(dd,loginTime)=datepart(dd,'2018-11-20 13:11:06.370') group by userId, cast(LOGINTIME as DATE)) as t1
right outer join    
(SELECT USERID,(sum (case when Logouttime is null or Logouttime ='' then 0 else datediff(Minute,LoginTime,Logouttime) end)) as Data1 
FROM LOGINREPORT  where datepart(ww,loginTime)=datepart(ww,'2018-11-19 13:11:06.370') group by userId, cast(LOGINTIME as DATE)) as t2 
on t1.UserID=t2.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers :)